# Strange Corrupted Frame ( in .MP4 Render )

Tags: animation, mesh, video

So, I rendered a

*Short animation (2 seconds) in my macbook pro (M1 2020) with following specs:

-Cycles (CPU)
-128 Samples
-Adaptive sampling
-NLM Deonoiser

-Ffmpeg Video (file format)
-MPEg-4 (Encoding /container)

*The Scene contains, as you can see in the image appended, following:
[image]

-Skull, Plane (Mesh)
-Second Skull (as Emitter for Smoke)
-Smoke Domain
-Lights

[*What the heck is this corrupted frame?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjxVk.jpg)

Do you guys have any idea what could cause a Frame look like that? during the video (2 seconds) i saw this 2 times.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp0RN.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post URLs for image.  Please include the images directly in your question.

Comment: didnt know u could do that, thx lol